# Rails redirecting to a show page instead of staying on index when attempting to sort

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I am writing a Rails app that is using partials and AJAX to allow the editing of an ActiveRecord entry from the index.

Recently I added in the ability to sort the entries by the various parts, in this particular case, Project Number, Editor, and Associated Producer. I did this using the Railscasts tutorial on the subject.

The sorting works great for the most part, however, once I update an entry, the sorting is reverted to the original state (before sorting) and if I attempt to sort again I am being taken to the show method of the updated entry.

My suspicion is that my controller isn't redirecting correctly, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Below is my controller's update method:

```
def update
    @whp_project=WhpProject.find(params[:id])
    @whp_projects=WhpProject.all
    @unarchived_projects = ArchiveStatus.find(0).whp_projects.all
    @to_archive_projects = ArchiveStatus.find(1).whp_projects.all
    editor_query = Editor.find_by initials: whp_project_params[:editor_initials]
    unknown_editor = Editor.find_by initials: 'UNK'
    get_ceta_id(@whp_project.project_number.to_i)
    @user_projects=WhpProject.where(ceta_username: current_user.ceta_username).all
    if editor_query != nil
      editor_id_assignment = editor_query.id
    else
      editor_id_assignment = unknown_editor.id
    end
    @whp_project.editor_id = editor_id_assignment
    @whp_project.update(:editor_id => editor_id_assignment)
    @whp_project.update(:ceta_username => @ceta_api_cuser)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @whp_project.update(whp_project_params)
        #format.html { redirect_to @whp_project, notice: 'Whp project was successfully updated.' }
        #format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @whp_project }``
        @whp_project.update(:ceta_username => @ceta_api_cuser)
        format.js
        format.html {redirect_to action: 'index'}
      else
        #format.html { render :edit }
        #format.json { render json: @whp_project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end

  end
```

Here is my _update.js.erb

```
$("#unarchivedajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'whp_projects/unarchived_projects') %>");
$("#otherunarchivedajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'whp_projects/other_users_unarchived_projects') %>");
$("#toarchiveajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'whp_projects/to_archive_projects', collection: @whp_projects, as: 'whp_project') %>");
$("#todeleteajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'whp_projects/to_restore_projects', collection: @whp_projects, as: 'whp_project') %>");
$("#torestoreajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'whp_projects/to_delete_projects', collection: @whp_projects, as: 'whp_project') %>");
$("#archivedajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'whp_projects/archived_projects', collection: @whp_projects, as: 'whp_project') %>");
```

my index method is as follows:

```
  def index
    @whp_projects = WhpProject.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    @unarchived_projects = ArchiveStatus.find(0).whp_projects.all
    @to_archive_projects = ArchiveStatus.find(1).whp_projects.all
    @user_projects=WhpProject.where(ceta_username: current_user.ceta_username).all
    @whp_project= WhpProject

  end
```

Thanks in advance,

I am happy to upload more if this isn't enough information to go on.

Comment: You'll need to pass the `sort_column` and `sort_direction` to the update as well. Or refresh just the updated entry, no the whole list

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the same sorting methods you use in the `index` action in the `update` one. Because the partials you render in `_update.js.erb` are gonna use that instance variables (and not the ones in `index`).

There is no redirection if you use AJAX.

Do something like this in the AJAX call to pass the current url parameters (change '/' for the path you are using):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PATCH',
  url: '/' + window.location.search,
  data: {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: so instead of using  `@whp_projects=WhpProject.all` i need to use the same reference as the index, i.e. `@whp_projects=WhpProject.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)`

Comment: so by updating this doesn't seem to have worked. The result is ultimately the same

Comment: you have to pass those parameters in the AJAX call, because they won't be available in the `update` action otherwise

Comment: Thanks, I'm not quite sure how to do this. Is there a useful place I could go to learn it?

Comment: I guess you do something like this `$.ajax({ type: 'PATCH', url: '/', data: {...}})` to update the entry. So pass the current params add them to the url with `window.location.search` (see updated answer)